# KDE Plasma crash after a few seconds (Kubuntu 18.04)

Tags: kubuntu, kde, crash, plasma, plasma-5

Since a few days I have the problem that after the start of my system only for a moment the desktop is visible (in fact, only the background image) and then plasma crashes. Everything else works fine, so I can start any application using KRunner, for example.

Some information:

- Kubuntu 18.04
- KDE Plasma 5.12.7
- KDE Framework 5.44.0
- Qt 5.9.5
- Kernel 4.15.0-45-generic (but the problem also exists under an older kernel)

What did I try:

- Added last packages removed via `apt-get autoremove` (`x11proto-dri2-dev:amd64` and `x11proto-gl-dev:amd64`)
- System update
- Disable startup programs
- Reset to default settings (`plasma-org.kde.plasma.desktop-appletsrc`, `plasmarc` and `plasmashellrc` removed)
- Create new user

Currently, I suspect the reason for my problem somewhere in the last updates made. The last packages that were updated before the problem occurred were: `libcurl4:amd64`, `spotify-client:amd64` and `libcurl3-gnutls:amd64`.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the (somewhat surprising) solution: **Blocked print jobs in CUPS** killed the complete desktop environment! So, if someone faces the same problem:

1. Go to the [CUPS server](http://localhost:631/) or to the print manager and remove all print jobs that have stopped or
2. run `lprm -`
3. Check if all print jobs could be removed! In my case, some jobs could not be removed. They belonged to a printer with a suspicious configuration, so in the end I simply removed the entire printer.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with an OpenSuse-Distro (Leap 15). Plasma desktop disappeared after a few seconds. When I disabled cups-server with

"systemctl disable cups" and reboot then plasma do not crash. 
Procedure:

1) Ctrl-Alt-F1   -> get a Console and logged in as root

2) "systemctl start cups" and "systemctl enable cups" (cups-server is running now and
   plasma-desktop crashed again - in OpenSuse you can see it with Ctrl-Alt-F7)

3) lpq  -> view the printer jobs queue for entries

4) lprm [jobID]  -> removed the halted jobs and reboot

Hope it helps somebody with the same problem